# WSO2 scheduled forwarding message processor consuming rate vs implementing MessageListener

Tags: java, wso2, activemq-classic, message-queue, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 ESB integration with ActiveMQ message broker. Today I was testing my application and found out forwarding rate in scheduled forwarding message processor is really slow. I tried to change forwarding rate in wso2 esb to make it less than 1000 milliseconds but nothing happened and consuming delay was even worse than before. I decided to take a look at scheduled forwarding message processor source code [here](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/message/processor/impl/ScheduledMessageProcessor.java) and I saw this line of comment :

// If this interval value is less than 1000 ms , ntask will throw an exception ....

Then I wrote a class which implements MessageListener Interface and creates a connection to one of activemq's queue and then I override onMessage method which would call when a new message publishes to the queue. then I ran my app and saw that consuming delay is much less than using ESB's scheduled forwarding message store. so my question is which approach is better? Is it really better to wrote a custom java class which consumes messages? Why forwarding rate is limited to 1000ms?

Comment: Read the comment in this JIRA, seems relevent https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3949

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense :)